# CMake dependency graph for custom targets

Tags: cmake

Is the `--graphviz` option of CMake supposed to get the dependency on custom targets?

Sample `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_executable(target0 test.cpp)
add_dependencies(target0 target1)
add_custom_target(target1 ALL
  COMMAND echo hello
)
```

The output file of "cmake --graphviz=test.dot ." would be:

```
digraph GG {
node [
  fontsize = "12"
];
    "node3" [ label="target0" shape="house"];
}
```

There isn't any trace of `target1`.

Comment: `add_dependencies` before creation of the target? Doesn't CMake complains for that?

Comment: Good spot, indeed looks strange, but my cmake did not complain. Anyway putting add_dependencies to the end of the file does not make any difference.

Comment: What's your CMake version?

Comment: Can reproduce on CMake 2.8.12.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [CMake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#opt:--graphvizfile) clearly states:

> **--graphviz=[file]**
>
> Generate a graphviz input file that will contain all the **library and executable** dependencies in the project. See the documentation for CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake for more details.

So, as far as I know, your custom target is neither - nor library, nor executable to be included into the resulting graph.

Comment: Since I've just started with cmake, it is difficult to understand from building graph prospective what the difference between executable and custom target is.

Answer (score 3):

As some might stumble over this question.

With CMake 3.17 custom targets can now be included
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/CMakeGraphVizOptions.html (related issue [17960](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17960))

> GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS
>
> Set to TRUE to include custom targets in the generated graphs.
>           Mandatory: NO
>           Default: FALSE
>
> GRAPHVIZ_IGNORE_TARGETS
>
> A list of regular expressions for names of targets to exclude from the generated graphs.
>           Mandatory: NO
>           Default: empty