# Generate dependency graph for custom targets with GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS=TRUE

Tags: cmake, graphviz

(Update with working solution at bottom)

From what I can tell, generating a dependency graph with custom targets is supported as of [CMake 3.17](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/module/CMakeGraphVizOptions.html#variable:GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS). However, when attempting to do so, I get no dependency mapping between my targets and I get this warning:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS
```

I stumbled upon this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61629256/1469905) answer, but it hasn't helped much. The next-closest thing I could find was an incomplete [Merge Request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/2626) to support some different use cases.

I'm running this on Windows, but I don't know if that could be the issue.

So, I'm stumped and could use some help before I file an issue against KitWare... since I think I am missing something really obvious. Any help would be so appreciated.

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(
    gviz 
    LANGUAGES NONE
)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT foo.txt
    COMMAND cmake --version > foo.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT bar.txt
    COMMAND cmake --version > bar.txt
    DEPENDS foo.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)


add_custom_target(
    foo
    DEPENDS foo.txt
)

add_custom_target(
    bar
    DEPENDS bar.txt
)
```

Command ran from console, and output:

Console Output:

```
cmake_graphviz> cmake --graphviz=group.dot -BNBuild -GNinja . -DGRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS=TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
Generate graphviz: cmake_graphviz/group.dot
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS


-- Build files have been written to: cmake_graphviz/NBuild
```

And finally, the `group.dot` file:

```
digraph "gviz" {
node [
  fontsize = "12"
];
subgraph clusterLegend {
  label = "Legend";
  color = black;
  edge [ style = invis ];
  legendNode0 [ label = "Executable", shape = egg ];
  legendNode1 [ label = "Static Library", shape = octagon ];
  legendNode2 [ label = "Shared Library", shape = doubleoctagon ];
  legendNode3 [ label = "Module Library", shape = tripleoctagon ];
  legendNode4 [ label = "Interface Library", shape = pentagon ];
  legendNode5 [ label = "Object Library", shape = hexagon ];
  legendNode6 [ label = "Unknown Library", shape = septagon ];
  legendNode7 [ label = "Custom Target", shape = box ];
  legendNode0 -> legendNode1 [ style = solid ];
  legendNode0 -> legendNode2 [ style = solid ];
  legendNode0 -> legendNode3;
  legendNode1 -> legendNode4 [ label = "Interface", style = dashed ];
  legendNode2 -> legendNode5 [ label = "Private", style = dotted ];
  legendNode3 -> legendNode6 [ style = solid ];
  legendNode0 -> legendNode7;
}
}
```

Working solution:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(
    gviz 
    LANGUAGES NONE
)

# Because I don't like cmake files flooding my root directory
file(COPY cmake/CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT foo.txt
    COMMAND cmake --version > foo.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT bar.txt
    COMMAND cmake --version > bar.txt
    DEPENDS foo.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)


add_custom_target(
    foo
    DEPENDS foo.txt
)

add_custom_target(bar)

add_dependencies(bar foo)
```

`cmake/CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake`

```
# This file sets some options to control GraphViz graphs.
set(GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_NAME "MyGraph")
set(GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS TRUE)
set(GRAPHVIZ_NODE_PREFIX "blah")
```

File List output:

```
group.dot
group.dot.bar
group.dot.foo
group.dot.bar.dependers
group.dot.bar.dependers
```

Now, the only issue I have is it doesn't seem to link dependencies via file outputs, but that is outside of the scope of this question :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the missing "links" in the graphs may be due to the unfinished state of the linked Kitware merge request. It sounds like there is still more work to do to make this custom target graphing feature complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/CMakeGraphVizOptions.html#variables-specific-to-the-graphviz-support), it states:

> The look and content of the generated graphs can be controlled using the file `CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake`. This file is first searched in `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, and then in `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`. If found, the variables set in it are used to adjust options for the generated Graphviz files.

So, instead of setting `GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS` in the `cmake` command line, set it in a file called `CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake`, and add this file to your top-level source directory.

An example `CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake`:

```
# This file sets some options to control GraphViz graphs.
set(GRAPHVIZ_GRAPH_NAME "MyGraph")
set(GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping it was something as obvious as that.